# How to set validation cookies for API using python requests?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I am attempting to scrape the following real-estate website for basic listing data:

https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/search?c=1&l=1&ob=pa&page=2

The website had an open API in the XHR tab which until now worked fine. However recently I have been getting a 401 Unauthorized error when I try make a request to the API. I suspect this is due to the introduction of a validation cookie. To fix this I tried making a request to the public website first, copying the cookies and then making a request to the API with those cookies however it has not worked. Another thing to note is the API can still be opened within a browser.

```
import requests as rq

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"}
url = "https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/api/search?"
params = [
    ("filter[category_id]", "2"),
    ("filter[furnished]","0"),
    ("filter[locations_ids][]","50"),
    ("filter[price_type]","y"),
    ("include","properties,properties.property_type,properties.property_images,properties.location_tree,properties.agent,properties.agent.languages,properties.broker,smart_ads,smart_ads.agent,smart_ads.broker,smart_ads.property_type,smart_ads.property_images,smart_ads.location_tree,direct_from_developer,direct_from_developer.property_type,direct_from_developer.property_images,direct_from_developer.location_tree,direct_from_developer.agent,direct_from_developer.broker,cts,cts.agent,cts.broker,cts.property_type,cts.property_images,cts.location_tree,similar_properties,similar_properties.agent,similar_properties.broker,similar_properties.property_type,similar_properties.property_images,similar_properties.location_tree,agent_smart_ads,agent_smart_ads.broker,agent_smart_ads.languages,agent_properties_smart_ads,agent_properties_smart_ads.agent,agent_properties_smart_ads.broker,agent_properties_smart_ads.location_tree,agent_properties_smart_ads.property_type,agent_properties_smart_ads.property_images"),
    ("page[limit]","25"),
    ("page[number]","2"),
    ("sort","nd")
]


#### Makes Request to public facing website and returns cookies in a dictionary

propurl = 'https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/search?c=1&l=1&ob=pa&page=2'

propbase = rq.get(propurl, headers=headers)

propcook = propbase.cookies

dictcookies = {}

for cookie in propcook:
     dictcookies[cookie.name] = cookie.value




# passes the cookies from the public website to the API and attempts to make a request
s
resp = rq.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, cookies=dictcookies)

resultat = []
for el in resp["included"]:
    if el["type"] == "property":
        data = {
            "name": el["attributes"]["name"],
            "default_price": el["attributes"]["default_price"],
            "bathroom_value": el["attributes"]["bathroom_value"],
            "bedroom_value": el["attributes"]["bedroom_value"],
            "coordinates" : el["attributes"]["coordinates"]}

        resultat.append(data)



print(resultat)
```

I would prefer to continue scraping the API as opposed to the website itself. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by 'public facing', and is the API private(or need authentication?)

Comment: I just mean the website itself as opposed to its api. Ie when you go to the website you don't land on the api page, it's a separate thing.

Comment: I don't believe its private. I think it generates an authentication cookie when you visit the website. You can open it from the website if you go through the xhr tab.

Comment: both the website and api don't need login, in your browser? if so, i don't think your cookie matters.

Comment: No neither needs a login to view, I thought it might be a cookie issue because when you open the api in one browser it works, but then if you copy the same address and paste it in another browser it returns 401 unauthorised.

Comment: i cannot verify your step to open the api. if you add `print(resp.url)` you'll get the full api url. paste into browser it always get 401. no matter how many times you browse the 'public web'.

Comment: If you open the developer tools on the website and go to the xhr tab you will see the API.

Comment: it starts with search%filter%5Bcategories, it is there. Try click the next page it will pop up.